# Downgrade to 1.4.12 (if necessary)

Tags: go-ethereum

because of DOS attack I have updated geth, but accidentally to 1.5.0 which is unstable, and now I want to downgrade to 1.4.12. Can someone instruct me how to downgrade to 1.4.12? Or even better, can someone tell me is it really necessary for me to downgrade? If there is no security concerns, then I'm OK with unstable version.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Regards,
Tomo

Answer (score 3):

If you run:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy geth
[sudo] password for b9lab-admin: 
geth:
  Installed: 1.5.0+125SNAPSHOT20160912085809xenial-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.5.0+127SNAPSHOT20160915114909xenial-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.5.0+127SNAPSHOT20160915114909xenial-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum-dev/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.5.0+125SNAPSHOT20160912085809xenial-0ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.11+12xenial-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

You can see the installed version with `***`. If you want another one you run:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove geth=1.5.0+125SNAPSHOT20160912085809xenial-0ubuntu1
$ sudo apt-get install geth=1.4.11+12xenial-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 the package is `sudo apt install geth=1.4.12+86trusty-0ubuntu1`