# Still stuck on 2283415

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

I have installed the new ethereum wallet and Geth with it. The Wallet is now 0.8.3 and geth 1.5. Yet, the wallet application and geth started in the terminal still have the same issue, they simply cannot sync 2283415.

I also tried Parity, which was supposed to be completely unaffected. It has synced the entire blockchain synched by not, but is ALSO STUCK on 2283415.

Help! Whats going on? I thought this problem had been fixed. Why is now parity also broken?

Max

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8731/synch-stuck-at-block-2283419 - you may want to try downgrading `geth` to 1.4.12 .

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. Parity eventually got over 2283415, it just took a while (around two hours). I got impatient and didn't let it run that long the first few tries. Now its fully synced.

So the answer is: Just leave Parity open and wait a few hours