# Sync Still Stuck After Downloading Mist Version 0.8.3

Tags: synchronization, bug

I was told that the new version would fix the syncing issue, but I just downloaded Version 0.8.3 and I'm still stuck on the exact same block.

My operating system is OSX.

Comment: Check your `geth` version - if you have the dev 1.5 version installed, this may not have been updated for the memory bug fix. See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8731/synch-stuck-at-block-2283419

Comment: @BokkyPooBah I don't have a technical background and have no idea what any of that means. I downloaded the latest wallet client that was released yesterday, so whatever version of Geth is in that is the one I have.

Comment: Try opening the menu Ethereum Wallet -> Check for updates... Confirm you are running the correct version as shown in the link.

Answer (score 1):

you have to delete you old blockchain and resync from scratch using Mist 0.8.3.  To do this go to home/library/ethereum/chaindata - delete the chaindata folder.  make sure you have your keystore files backed up. A new sync is fast with this version of geth if it starts with an empty db